# Process Control Issue

Tags: python, process-control

Why doesn't the loop end the first time `collatz()` returns 1?

```
def collatz():
    global number
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
        print(number)
        return number
    else:
        number = 3 * number + 1
        print(number)
        return number

try:
    number = int(input('Please enter an integer except zero.\n'))
except ValueError:
    print("ValueError: invalid value.")
    number = int(input('You must enter an integer except zero.\n'))


while collatz() != 1:   # if input(4), the output will be: 4 2 1 4 2 1 
    collatz()


# another way, which works:
while number != 1:  --> # also input(4), the output will be: 4 2 1
    collatz()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first method, you call `collatz()` twice in each loop:

- once in `while collatz() != 1:`, where the return value gets tested. If it returns 1 at this point, you will exit the loop.
- a second time inside the body of the loop. This time, the return value doesn't get tested, so even if it is 1, you'll just go back to the `while` line.

So, when you input 4, your output is:

- 4 (your input)
- 2 (while line)
- 1 (body - so the loop won't end)
- 4 (while line)
- 2 (body)
- 1 (while line - now the loop ends)

You could also write your loop like:

```
while collatz() != 1:
    pass  # do nothing
```

A bit of advice:

- Avoid using global variables, they quickly become evil
- Separate concerns: for example, let your `collatz()` function take a number as parameter, and return the next value. Leave the printing to the rest of the code.
- try not to repeat yourself.

You could modify it like this, for example:

```
def collatz(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * number + 1
    return n

try:
    number = int(input('Please enter an integer except zero.\n'))
except ValueError:
    print("ValueError: invalid value.")
    number = int(input('You must enter an integer except zero.\n'))


while True:  # infinite loop
    number = collatz(number)
    print(number)
    if number == 1:
        # we break out of the loop
        break
```

Comment: **Thanks for your advice.**